# Why do answers to good questions always get a higher score than the question itself?

Tags: discussion, voting

This is always the case and I am so curious to know why. Here are examples (the highest voted questions from various sites):

- Stack Overflow: [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array)
- Super User: [What is the cURL command-line syntax to do a POST request?](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request)
- Ask Ubuntu: [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)
- Ask Different: [macOS Mojave: invalid active developer path](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-mojave-invalid-active-developer-path)
- Server Fault: [Our security auditor is an idiot. How do I give him the information he wants?](https://serverfault.com/questions/293217/our-security-auditor-is-an-idiot-how-do-i-give-him-the-information-he-wants)

Comment: Folks, please do NOT answer closed questions in comments.